# How to convert the output to a variable?

Tags: powershell

This is the table:

[image]

I use `import-CSV` to get the data from the table:

```
$Process = @()
$Energy = @()

Import-Csv C:\Users\Shuai\Desktop\test\Test.csv |`
ForEach-Object 
{
    $Process += $_."Process"
    $Energy += $_.Energy
}

$inputName = Read-Host -Prompt "Process"

if ($Process -contains $inputName)
{
    $Where = [array]::IndexOf($Process, $inputName)
    $Energy[$Where]
}
```

If I type `Construction` it will give me 0.1 as the value of `Energy`. But it cannot be used to do any calculation. 
For an example, if I use

```
$xx = $Energy[$Where]
$XY = $xx * 5
```

What I got is `0.10.10.10.10.10.1`. I don not want to just repeat the value for five times. I need `0.5` for the result.
Is there any method to use this value as the normal variable (for normal calculations)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's treating it as a string instead of a floating point number.  You'll need to cast it:

```
$xx = $Energy[$Where] -as [double]
```

Or:

```
$xx = [double]$Energy[$Where]
```

Or:

```
[double]$xx = $Energy[$Where]
```